Plantuml file not included in rst document
Given the following rst:
.. uml:: ClassDiagram.puml
   :caption: ClassDiagram

conf.py contains only the extension:
extensions = ["sphinxcontrib.plantuml"]

With Sphinx, I build an html page.
The included uml diagram is as follows:

This image is generated with the input as the filename, instead of the contents of the filename.
What am I doing wrong?
I cannot find any existing questions about this issue.
Python version: 3.12.3
Sphinx version: 7.2.6

I think you're saying that the UML diagram renders the literal text "ClassDiagram.puml", rather than the content in a file by that name.  I can't reproduce that problem.
Your minimal reproducible example doesn't show the Sphinx build log, or the content of file ClassDiagram.puml.
PlantUML is liberal with what it accepts so you can omit a lot - like the @startuml @enduml tags - and it will still parse/render OK.  Whether I pass an implicit filename, or an explicit UML script, the Sphinx extension seems to distinguish the arguments properly.  So...
.. uml::
    :caption: MyExample

    ClassDiagram.puml

will render just fine, as is (live server demo).
.. uml:: ClassDiagram.puml
    :caption: MyExample

will render the content of that file if the file exists, or fail WARNING: PlantUML file "ClassDiagram.puml" cannot be read: [Errno 2] No such file or directory if the file doesn't exist.
.. uml:: ClassDiagram.puml
    :caption: MyExample

    a dummy
    UML script

will fail WARNING: uml directive cannot have both content and a filename argument [docutils].
.. uml:: 
    :caption: MyExample

    a dummy
    UML script

will fail /home/mc1/Desktop/temp/index.rst:35: WARNING: error while running plantuml (the content got passed to PlantUML, but was rejected as invalid syntax).
Next steps...

What does your build log show?
Does the file ClassDiagram.puml actually exist?
Does shifting the UML script out from the file, in to the directive block work?
Any stray file line endings or non-printable characters?
The Kroki Sphinx extension instead?
Maybe you solved the problem - please feedback for the community's benefit?

.
# My environment
$ python --version
Python 3.12.3
$ sphinx-build --version
sphinx-build 8.1.3
$ find ~/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages -iname "*plant*"
sphinxcontrib_plantuml-0.30

